# How do I count comma-separated values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have a variable holding values separated by a comma (Implode), and I'm trying to get the total count of the values in that variable. However. count() is just returning 1.

I've tried converting the comma-separated values to a properly formatted array which still spits out1.

So here is the quick snippet where the `sarray` session is equal to value1,value2,value3:

```
$schools = $_SESSION['sarray'];
$result = count($schools);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to [explode](http://de.php.net/explode) `$schools` into an actual array:

```
$schools = $_SESSION['sarray'];
$schools_array = explode(",", $schools);
$result = count($schools_array);
```

if you just need the count, and are 100% sure it's a clean comma separated list, you could also use [substr_count()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) which may be marginally faster and, more importantly, easier on memory with very large sets of data:

```
$result = substr_count( $_SESSION['sarray'], ",") +1; 
 // add 1 if list is always a,b,c;
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, would vote you guys up--but I'm new here.

Comment: @pekka. Voted you up for the options ;) however, for substr_count, it should be +1

Comment: @pekka. Not in the count(), but in the substr_count() example ;)

Answer (score 3):

Should be

```
$result = count(explode(',',$schools));
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, its simpler than that:

```
$count = substr_count($schools, ',') + 1;
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but I think you mean `substr_count`, and why -1? Surely +1?

Comment: @adam yeah, you are right, I typed the response in a hurry :)

Answer (score 2):

If there is `sarray` key set in `session` array, the count will return 1 for an **empty string** as well.

```
$session = array('sarray' => '');

$count = count(explode(',', $session['sarray']));

echo $count;

// => 1
```

So, if you want to count the number of items in the array, you will have to add an **additional check** for `empty`.

```
$session = array('sarray' => '');

$count = !empty($session['sarray']) ? count(explode(',', $session['sarray'])) : 0;

echo $count;

// => 0
```

Now, let's check if this works with items inside `sarray`.

```
$session = array('sarray' => 'foo, bar');

$count = !empty($session['sarray']) ? count(explode(',', $session['sarray'])) : 0;

echo $count;

// => 2
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$schools = $_SESSION['sarray'];
$array = explode(',', $schools); array_walk($array, 'trim');
$count = count($array);
```

The `array_walk($array, 'trim')` will remove any trailing space in elements value. :)